# How to set an "and condition" in search query

Tags: search, search-results, search-scope

I have a searchable column userd in more then a list. When I search with the search server (by code or by web) my content it works well...

I need to use the same column "more times" in a query and obtain results like an logic AND.

I tried:

ColName: Val1 Val2   //but 2nd one is taken as a generic value not linked to the column

ColName: "Val1 Val2" //but is different from "Val2 Val1" and i need to be equal

ColName: Val1 ColName:Val2 //but works as an or

ColName: Val1+Val2 //but doesn't work at all..

Any suggestion? I tried to look at documentation, but is a little mess!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll need:

```
(ColName:Val1) AND (ColName:Val2)
```

Without the AND, yes, they are implicitly OR'd, as they're the same column. [This is mentioned in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394509.aspx), but it doesn't make it clear that you can explicitly AND them.

If the column names were different, they would be explicitly AND'd - but in exactly the same way you could explicitly OR them.